# How to hide a list without javascript

Tags: html, wordpress

I have this code and I would like to have the list be collapsed by default. [Here](http://www.cssportal.com/css3-preview/demo/css-menu-ex1.html) is what it does now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
   <title>menu mockup</title>
   <style type="text/css">
      .show {display: none; }
      .hide:focus + .show {display: inline; }
      .hide:focus { display: none; }
      .hide:focus ~ #list { display:none; }
      @media print { .hide, .show { display: none; } }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   <p>Here's a list</p>
      <div>
         <a href="#" class="hide">[hide]</a>
         <a href="#" class="show">[show]</a>
         <ol id="list">
            <li>item 1</li>
            <li>item 2</li>
            <li>item 3</li>
         </ol>
      </div>
   <p>How about that?</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems to do *nothing* now? Is it meant to do something/anything?

Comment: I doesn't seem to work in chrome. I dont know why. I works in firefox and ie

Answer (score 2):

For this to work in pure CSS requires a change to the HTML (since CSS can only target elements that appear later in the DOM (either as later-siblings, or descendants, or a combination of those two) than the elements upon which they're styled. So, the HTML is now:

```
<p>Here's a list</p>
<div id="top">
    <ol id="list">
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
    </ol>
    <a href="#top" class="hide">[hide]</a>
    <a href="#list" class="show">[show]</a>
</div>
<p>How about that?</p>​
```

Note also that the `div` now has an `id` in order to allow for the list to be *hidden* (again, using just CSS and basic HTML).

The CSS is somewhat convoluted, though explained through `/* comments in the CSS itself */`:

```
.show,
.hide {
    /* allows for the links to be positioned 'ahead' of the list
       whose appearance they control */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.1em;
    /* allows for an assigned width, height, etc... */
    display: inline-block;
    width: 5em;
    height: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    text-align: center;
}

.hide {
    left: 0;
}

.show {
    /* this is why we have an assigned width */
    left: 5.1em;
}

#list {
    /* hides on page-load */
    display: none;
}

#list:target {
    /* when clicking the 'show' link the #list is targeted
       and is shown */
    display: block;
}

#list:target ~ .show {
    /* reduces the opacity of the 'show' link, when
       the list is already shown */
    opacity: 0.3;
}

#list:target ~ .hide {
    /* when the list is shown, the 'hide' link is visible */
    opacity: 1;
}

#top {
    /* allows the links to be positioned visually ahead of,
       and relative to, the menu */
    position: relative;
    /* slightly greater than the defined height of
       the link elements */
    padding-top: 2.2em;
}

#top .hide,
#top:target  .hide {
    /* hides the 'hide' link when the list is, itself, hidden */
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/78QBU/).

A slightly revised (another element added to wrap the links) version, to allow for more easily positioning them (rather than having to manually work out how wide each link is before setting the `left` position):

```
<p>Here's a list</p>
<div id="top">
    <ol id="list">
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
    </ol>
    <!-- could use a div, it doesn't matter -->
    <span id="controls">
        <a href="#top" class="hide">[hide]</a>
        <a href="#list" class="show">[show]</a>
    </span>
</div>
<p>How about that?</p>​
```

With the CSS:

```
#controls {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.1em;
    left: 0;
    height: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
}

.show,
.hide {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 5em;
    text-align: center;
}

#list {
    display: none;
}

#top {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 2.2em;
}

#list:target {
    display: block;
}

#list:target ~ #controls .hide {
    opacity: 1;
}

#list:target ~ #controls .show {
    opacity: 0.3;
}

#top #controls .hide {
    opacity: 0.3;
}
#top:target #controls .hide {
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/78QBU/1/).

Or, instead, using [`visibility: hidden` / `visibility: visible;`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/78QBU/2/).

Comment: thanks for that. I now have another problem I thought I could just drop this code on the webpage I was working on in WordPress but for some reason I am having trouble. [this](http://amerihomesgroup.com/about-us/locations/#list) is the site. the list are in tables. what would make it not work here?

Comment: Reproduce the HTML and CSS and add to a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) where I can play with it and see what's going on, and then I'll try and help.

Comment: I have been working on some other projects but here it is http://jsfiddle.net/kkxxr/. I have got it with this to hide one of the lists at a time but not all of them. It also doesn't work in chrome. thanks for the help

Answer (score -1):

This html code collapses the list by default

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
   <title>menu mockup</title>
   <style type="text/css">
      .show {display: inline; text-decoration: none;}
      .hide {display: none; text-decoration: none;}
      #list {display: none;}
      .show:focus + .hide {display: inline;}
      .hide:focus + #list { display:none;}
      .show:focus ~ #list { display:inline;}
      .show:focus { display:none;}

   </style>
</head>
<body>
   <p>Here's a list</p>
      <div>


         <a href="#" class="show">&#x25BC</a>
         <a href="#" class="hide">&#x25B2</a>
         <ol id="list">
            <li>item 1</li>
            <li>item 2</li>
            <li>item 3</li>
         </ol>

      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```